# NVENC Nvidia Encoder D3D11 Wrong image dimension and other questions

Tags: c++, h.264, directx-11, nvenc

first a few basic information:

OS: Win7 64Bit | GPU: GTX970

I have a staging ID3D11Texture2D wich I would like to encode.

I would like to use the texture directly via **nvEncRegisterResource** but it seems that i could only pass a D3D9 and no D3D11 texture. Otherwise i get a **NV_ENC_ERR_UNIMPLEMENTED**.

Thefore, I create an input buffer and fill it manually.

The texture is in the format **DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM**. The format **DXGI_FORMAT_NV12** is possibly only from Windows 8 onwards.

The input buffer format is **NV_ENC_BUFFER_FORMAT_ARGB**. This should also be 8 bits per color channel. Since the alpha value is interchanged I expect a wrong picture but it should still be encoded.

My process so far:

- Create ID3D11Texture2D render texture
- Create ID3D11Texture2D staging texture
- Create NVENC input buffer with nvEncCreateInputBuffer
- Create NVENC output buffer with nvEncCreateBitstreamBuffer

:: Update routine ::

- Render into render texture
- CopyResource() to staging texture
- Fill NVENC input buffer from staging texture
- Encode frame
- Get data from NVENC output buffer

As you can see, I encode only one frame per update.

So far everything works without error, but if i look at the frame the picture size is wrong.

[image]

That should be 1280 x 720. If I also try to pass more than one frame then I get a broken file.

I understand that in H.264 my first frame is an I-frame and the following should be a P-frame.

Now my code:

**:: Create input buffer**

```
NVENCSTATUS RenderManager::CreateInputBuffer()
{
    NVENCSTATUS nvStatus = NV_ENC_SUCCESS;

    NV_ENC_CREATE_INPUT_BUFFER createInputBufferParams = {};
    createInputBufferParams.version = NV_ENC_CREATE_INPUT_BUFFER_VER;
    createInputBufferParams.width = m_width;
    createInputBufferParams.height = m_height;
    createInputBufferParams.memoryHeap = NV_ENC_MEMORY_HEAP_SYSMEM_CACHED;
    createInputBufferParams.bufferFmt = NV_ENC_BUFFER_FORMAT_ARGB;

    nvStatus = m_pEncodeAPI->nvEncCreateInputBuffer(m_pEncoder, &createInputBufferParams);
    if (nvStatus != NV_ENC_SUCCESS) return nvStatus;

    m_pEncoderInputBuffer = createInputBufferParams.inputBuffer;

    return nvStatus;
}
```

**:: Create output buffer**

```
NVENCSTATUS RenderManager::CreateOutputBuffer()
{
    NVENCSTATUS nvStatus = NV_ENC_SUCCESS;

    NV_ENC_CREATE_BITSTREAM_BUFFER createBitstreamBufferParams = {};
    createBitstreamBufferParams.version = NV_ENC_CREATE_BITSTREAM_BUFFER_VER;
    createBitstreamBufferParams.size = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    createBitstreamBufferParams.memoryHeap = NV_ENC_MEMORY_HEAP_SYSMEM_CACHED;

    nvStatus = m_pEncodeAPI->nvEncCreateBitstreamBuffer(m_pEncoder, &createBitstreamBufferParams);
    if (nvStatus != NV_ENC_SUCCESS) return nvStatus;

    m_pEncoderOutputBuffer = createBitstreamBufferParams.bitstreamBuffer;

    return nvStatus;
}
```

**:: Fill input buffer**

```
NVENCSTATUS RenderManager::WriteInputBuffer(ID3D11Texture2D* pTexture)
{
    NVENCSTATUS nvStatus = NV_ENC_SUCCESS;
    HRESULT result = S_OK;

    // get data from staging texture
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    result = m_pContext->Map(pTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedResource);
    if (FAILED(result)) return NV_ENC_ERR_GENERIC;

    m_pContext->Unmap(pTexture, 0);

    // lock input buffer
    NV_ENC_LOCK_INPUT_BUFFER lockInputBufferParams = {};
    lockInputBufferParams.version = NV_ENC_LOCK_INPUT_BUFFER_VER;
    lockInputBufferParams.inputBuffer = m_pEncoderInputBuffer;

    nvStatus = m_pEncodeAPI->nvEncLockInputBuffer(m_pEncoder, &lockInputBufferParams);
    if (nvStatus != NV_ENC_SUCCESS) return nvStatus;

    unsigned int pitch = lockInputBufferParams.pitch;

    //ToDo: Convert R8G8B8A8 to A8R8G8B8

    // write into buffer
    memcpy(lockInputBufferParams.bufferDataPtr, mappedResource.pData, m_height * mappedResource.RowPitch);

    // unlock input buffer
    nvStatus = m_pEncodeAPI->nvEncUnlockInputBuffer(m_pEncoder, m_pEncoderInputBuffer);

    return nvStatus;
}
```

**:: Encode frame**

```
NVENCSTATUS RenderManager::EncodeFrame()
{
    NVENCSTATUS nvStatus = NV_ENC_SUCCESS;

    int8_t* qpDeltaMapArray = NULL;
    unsigned int qpDeltaMapArraySize = 0;

    NV_ENC_PIC_PARAMS encPicParams = {};
    encPicParams.version = NV_ENC_PIC_PARAMS_VER;
    encPicParams.inputWidth = m_width;
    encPicParams.inputHeight = m_height;
    encPicParams.inputBuffer = m_pEncoderInputBuffer;
    encPicParams.outputBitstream = m_pEncoderOutputBuffer;
    encPicParams.bufferFmt = NV_ENC_BUFFER_FORMAT_ARGB;
    encPicParams.pictureStruct = NV_ENC_PIC_STRUCT_FRAME;
    encPicParams.qpDeltaMap = qpDeltaMapArray;
    encPicParams.qpDeltaMapSize = qpDeltaMapArraySize;

    nvStatus = m_pEncodeAPI->nvEncEncodePicture(m_pEncoder, &encPicParams);

    return nvStatus;
}
```

**:: Read from output buffer**

```
NVENCSTATUS RenderManager::ReadOutputBuffer()
{
    NVENCSTATUS nvStatus = NV_ENC_SUCCESS;

    // lock output buffer
    NV_ENC_LOCK_BITSTREAM lockBitstreamBufferParams = {};
    lockBitstreamBufferParams.version = NV_ENC_LOCK_BITSTREAM_VER;
    lockBitstreamBufferParams.doNotWait = 0;
    lockBitstreamBufferParams.outputBitstream = m_pEncoderOutputBuffer;

    nvStatus = m_pEncodeAPI->nvEncLockBitstream(m_pEncoder, &lockBitstreamBufferParams);
    if (nvStatus != NV_ENC_SUCCESS) return nvStatus;

    void* pData = lockBitstreamBufferParams.bitstreamBufferPtr;
    unsigned int size = lockBitstreamBufferParams.bitstreamSizeInBytes;

    // read from buffer
    PlatformManager::SaveToFile("TEST", static_cast<char*>(pData), size);

    // unlock output buffer
    nvStatus = m_pEncodeAPI->nvEncUnlockBitstream(m_pEncoder, m_pEncoderOutputBuffer);

    return nvStatus;
}
```

m_width and m_height are always 1280 and 720.

Why is the image size wrong and how i have to fill the input buffer with more than one frame ?

Many thanks for your help,

Alexander

Comment: When NVENC encodes the first frame, it generates one or more NALUs containing the encoded frame, but also two special NALUs with metadata (called SPS and PPS), including the resolution, which any player software needs in order to render the stream. Are you sure you are storing the whole output buffer? (You should probably post that code as well.)